# Views output realname field as a contextual link

Tags: 7, views

Contextual is set up to display all content from a user for a specific content type.
www.example.com/users/realname/gallery where realname is contextual filter.
[Realname](https://www.drupal.org/project/realname) is used with token that reflects field from registration: field-choose-realname.

Lets say we have 2 users and 1st writes "One" as realname and 2nd writes "One Two".
Realname contextual filter is setup to use lowercase and change spaces to dash.

Here is what happens:
www.example.com/users/one/gallery - ok

www.example.com/users/one-two/gallery - page not found error
www.example.com/users/one%20two/gallery - ok

For Contextual "when the filter is in the URL or a default is provided" i am using this php code (i did not write it so i have no clue what it does really):

```
if (!isset($argument)) {
  return FALSE;
}
$query = db_query('SELECT uid, realname FROM {realname} WHERE realname = :realname', array(':realname' => $argument));
$row = $query->fetchAssoc();
if (isset($row['uid'])) {
  return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
```

To better explain what i want to do:
Get sidebar menu like on myspace for bands. When you land on bands page you can use sidebar menu to check their foto galleries, band members, video gallery and links must be made with a field that is not default username (it can be realname module or some other text field). Field validation is used so i do not get same name twice, and all links in pathauto are made example.com/bands/realname.
To repeat again it does work if realname contains 1 word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the contextual filter to transform spaces to dashes will not make the Realname field in the database contain dashes, so the filter fails. In your url you look for `one-two`, in the database this is `One Two` they are not the same and it doesn't work (`one-two ≠ One Two`).

First make sure [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) is installed and enabled. It will provide your users with a pretty url. This will make sure every user has a unique path. 
If you replace spaces and dashes in the URL as you do now, the contextual filter for these users `One Two, One-Two, One'Two` will all become `one-two` even if they are if fact different users. So your results will be mixed up. Pathauto will make sure they become unique; `one-two`, `one-two2` and so on.

Do not rely on simple pattern matching, but use the uid from the instead. Luckily we can hide this entirely from the url by using a View's contextual filter.

**Update**

It seems I have missed a module requirement; [Sub-pathauto (Sub-path URL Aliases)](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto).

> The Drupal Path module matches only full URLs when creating
>   SEO-friendly aliases. This module extends that behavior by also
>   matching known sub-paths and replacing them with their respective
>   alias.
>
> For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites
>   the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased
>   URL users/admin/contact instead.

The is required to properly obtain the UID from the url.

Then create your view as follows:
[image: View]

Use must use the unaliased path for the `path`. So if your user is at `/users/url-safe-realname` and your gallery at `/users/url-safe-realname/gallery`, you enter `/user/%/gallery` (omit the s in users pathauto adds if using default settings).

For the contextual filter, in the *WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED* section, check `Specify validation criteria`, choose `user` and `numeric UIDs`.

The result will be a page that has the url-safe realname in the path and shows only content created by the user:

[image: Result]

Comment: User id is 153453 or something like that and Realname is profile name which is "One Two". I want nice and clean looking urls thats why i want to use Realname as contextual filter and not uid.

Comment: You can keep realname in the url and still use the uid for the contextual filter. Just try it.

Comment: I tried it, but got same results. I have updated question, maybe to clear things up.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Neograph. Pathauto is installed, unique link is generated for each user using field field-choose-realname. Realname module uses this field. In views i have setup everything like you and i get ok results if the field-choose-realname has 1 word. If it has 2 words it breaks up becouse of the dash in the link, and if i let it go undashed i get ok results but link looks really ugly. Conclusion is that view contextual is working ok since it get good results for 1 word link, and for the link where it uses %20 (space) instead of dash.

Comment: A realname field will include spaces if they are in the name. You can use this for pauthauto aliasing, so it will take care of the spaces, but you should not be using the realname field to build the url, you should obtain the user url alias and append `/gallery` to it.

Comment: So its not possible to use Realname to build the link ? Event tho in views i set use dashes instead of space ?

Comment: Better not. If you do that, names `One Two` and `One-Two` will be considered the same while in fact they are not.

Comment: If they were considered same, it would work already (link: one-two = error: link: one%20two = ok; link: one two = ok).

Comment: I updated the question on the bottom to better explain why i want realname. Point is to have clean links for all bands and to give user who is making content privacy, and when they make any content it is connected to band name, not username.

Comment: I've updated the answer... It appeared I forgot to mention a required module. I assumed it would work without because I am used to it. Also included screenshots and a slightly more detailed explanation.

Comment: just to be clear, users reffers to gruop of users not to user that is in drupal by dafault. for this example users = bands so the link looks like this: www.example.com/bands/%/gallery where % = bandname (realname). Going to test what you wrote.

Comment: _just to be clear, users refers to group of users not to user that is in Drupal by default._ A group of users that are not the default Drupal users? I don't understand what you mean. The question constantly mentions users.

Comment: i mean "users" in link = bands.

Comment: I can rewrite the question from start or we can move to discoussion not to spam here, but i dont know how to turn it on.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40270/views-output-realname-field-as-a-contextual-link